# Does Tor still monitor "shadow" relays?

Tags: onion-services, consensus, traffic-analysis, hsdir, flags

I've been researching methods to monitor hidden services for a university project. I came across [this paper](https://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2013/papers/4977a080.pdf) which talks about injecting relays as hidden service directories to gather onion addresses. To make this affordable, the researchers take advantage of what they call "shadowing".

From the paper:

> However, by inspecting the Tor source code we noticed
>   that while only two relays per IP appear in the Consensus,
>   all running relays are monitored by the authorities; more
>   importantly, statistics on them is collected, including the
>   uptime which is used to decide which flags a relay will
>   be assigned.

This would allow them to get the necessary flags to get the HSDir flag for more than two relays on a single IP.

> Our approach is based on shadow relays described
>   in the previous section. An attacker can use this artifact of
>   Tor’s design as follows. She can rent 50 IP addresses and
>   run 24 relays on each of them for 25 hours thus running
>   1200 Tor instances in total; 100 of them should appear in
>   the consensus. The fingerprints of the public keys of the
>   relays should fall into every second gap in the fingerprint
>   circle. At the end of 25 hour time period all of the relays
>   will have HSDir flags but only 100 of them will appear in
>   the consensus and the rest will be shadow relays. The idea
>   is to gradually make active relays unreachable to the Tor
>   authorities so that shadow relays become active and thus
>   gradually cover all gaps in the circular list during 24 hours.

I was wondering if this technique is still possible given that the paper is from 2013 and this might have been patched since then.

Additional question:

Now that the "stable" flag is a requirement to get the HSDir flag, how long does a relay need to run in order to get the HSDir flag?

From the Tor documentation:

> "Stable" -- A router is 'Stable' if it is active, and either its Weighted
>      MTBF is at least the median for known active routers or its Weighted MTBF
>      corresponds to at least 7 days.

Does this mean that 7 days of uptime is not a requirement for the "stable" flag?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it is still possible to do those kind of attacks against the network. However Tor tries to detect [bad relays](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/ReportingBadRelays) and block them from participating in the network. So there is a high chance that your research doesn't lead to satisfactory results.

Tor has created a [Research Safety Board](https://research.torproject.org/safetyboard/). You can ask them for advice on how to best conduct your research while not harm the actual users.